# Javascript : loop through nested arrays that contain objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a tow arrays that contain objects I want to compare to find unmatched values from the objects and return the object if contain unmatched value  but I'm confused I get wrong value any help or idea it's my code

```js
var firstarry=[{'name':'alex','age':22,'numbersOne':['111','222','333','444','555'],'location':'iq'},{'name':'jan','age':33,'numbersOne':['111','222','333','444'],'location':'in'}];
var secondarray=[{'name':'aga','age':12,'numbersTwo':['111','222','333','444'],'location':'usa'},{'name':'jan','age':35,'numbersTwo':['111','222','333','444'],'location':'uk'}];
var un_mached_rows=[]; 
var tmp_recorder={};
firstarry.forEach(function(firstArrayElements){

  if(firstArrayElements.hasOwnProperty('numbersOne')){
    firstArrayElements.numbersOne.forEach(function(numberOneElements){
      secondarray.forEach(function(secondArrayElements){

        if(secondArrayElements.hasOwnProperty('numbersTwo')){
          secondArrayElements.numbersTwo.forEach(function(numbersTwoElements){

            if(numberOneElements!=numbersTwoElements){
              tmp_recorder.name = firstArrayElements.name;
              tmp_recorder.age = firstArrayElements.age;
              tmp_recorder.location = firstArrayElements.location;
              tmp_recorder.numbers = numberOneElements;
              un_mached_rows.push(tmp_recorder);
              tmp_recorder;                  
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
console.log(un_mached_rows);
```

it should return the `un_mached_rows=[{'name':'alex','age':22,'numbers':'555'}]`
but now it return 56 wrong  record

Comment: please add **why** you want the result.

Comment: Also, you need to let us know if you want to compare every property to see if is different, or just `numbersOne` and `numbersTwo`, and if the first array object should be compared to the entire secondArray or just with the first object of secondArray.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty big logic error in your routine.

You basically are comparing each element of the first array, with each element of the second array.... and even if the first array matches 1 element in the first array it won't match the rest so you get every other element of array 2 added to your results... IE:

array1 = 1,2
array2 = 1,2,3

First outer loop value from array1 is 1....

Looping through array2 first time through the inner loop array2 element is 1 so 1=1 and they match.... so nothing is added to your result, however on loop 2 and 3 of the inner loop  1 will not match 2 or 3, so they are both added to the result array...

Then the outer loop value changes to 2 and you get the same behavior.

Comment: Your information is true, but it would be nice if you could suggest a way to make it work correctly.